# onActivityResult() does not call on creating new Account while google sign-in

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-authentication, google-signin

I have integrated google sign-in. On click of sign-in button "choose account" dialog is getting open. If I choose already created google account for login, getting callback in onActivityResult() but on creating new account never got callback.

Code is here.

```
googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions);

Handling callback:

```
private void signIn() {
    googleSignInClient.signOut();
    Intent signInIntent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 123);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 123 && data != null) {
        handleSignInResult(data);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Intent data) {
    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> signInTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = signInTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
            updateUI(googleSignInAccount);
        }
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Don't what is wrong with this code. Is this google issue?

Gradle:

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
```

Comment: check your result code. is getting success?

Comment: @RajasekaranM - Without getting callback how can i check result?

Comment: Below is the response that I have received on the open/known google sign in issue. I'm afraid there is nothing much that we can do here other than wait and watch.. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1297

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until we get release update from google, here is the another work around by which I got solution .

As we know, onActivityResult() is not called only when user adds new account, but onRestart() and start() methods get called.

Below is the code to open google consent screen to picked up account or add new account.

```
Intent signInIntent = loginHandler.mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GET_TOKEN);
```

Before calling above code I keep currently registered google accounts count. i.e 3 accounts registered in my device.

Once user complete add new account process, onStart() method will get call and here I checked again google account count by below code:

```
Account[] googleAccounts = AccountManager.get(activity).getAccountsByType("com.google");

if (googleAccounts != null && googleAccounts.length > 0) {
    if (lastGoogleAccounts == 0) {
        lastGoogleAccounts = googleAccounts.length;
    } else {
        if (googleAccounts.length > lastGoogleAccounts) {
         // do login
```

}

if new count is > last count, it means new account is registered and redirect to home screen.